# Can you use a boolean in ORDER BY to sort all Objects that have this field true to the top of the query result?

Tags: apex, soql

I am trying to use ORDER BY on a checkbox field on an Object so I can have all Objects that have this field marked true at the top of my query result.

This is the first condition I am using in ORDER BY section of my query. The rest is pushing objects that have fields as null to the bottom of the query result and a date field being used to have the objects having the most recent date pushed to the top of the query result.

Is it just `ORDER BY Boolean_Field__c NULLS LAST, Example_Field__c NULLS LAST, Date_Field__c NULLS LAST DESC` or can you only use ORDER BY on fields that are not boolean?

Comment: Checkbox fields are never NULL - they are always either False or True

Answer (score 3):

This is one of those things that would generally be faster to test for yourself, assuming you have access to an org.

Anyway, the answer is that **we are able to include Checkbox** (i.e. Boolean) type fields in the `ORDER BY` clause.

The [SOQL Documentation on `ORDER BY`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select_orderby.htm) corroborates this.

> The following limitations apply to data types when using ORDER BY:
>
> - These data types are not supported: multi-select picklist, rich text area, long text area, encrypted (if enabled), and data category group reference (if Salesforce Knowledge is enabled).
> - All other data types are supported, with the following caveats:
>
>   - Corporate currency always sorts using corporate currency value, if available.
>   - phone data does not include any special formatting when sorting, for example, non-numeric characters such as dash or parentheses are included in the sorting.
>   - picklist sorting is defined by the picklist sort determined during setup.